# Hide "Successfully Updated" notifications from Google Play/Market

Tags: google-play-store, notifications

I have a lot of apps on auto-update and I *really* don't care when most of them update. I almost always have 3 notifications saying some app has successfully updated.

Is there any way I can the notifications off? I'm on Android 2.3.5, Motorola Electrify. I *think* I have the latest version of Market since it updated to Google Play on its own. I don't see settings for this anywhere in Google Play or the device's settings. FWIW I'm not rooted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From 4.1 onwards it's possible to do so in the System Settings/Apps/Google Play Store. Uncheck the box that says Show Notifications. That kills all notifications for the app.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, I didn't even think to check this after getting a 4.2 device

Answer (score 5):

No, i don't think its controllable. At least i haven't found any set of *Advanced Settings* in *Google Play* to enable/disable such notifications. So, I think, at the moment, you have to live with it, though a request can be made to Google for improvements at http://code.google.com/p/android/

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen anything in Google Play or the device settings at all...was hoping I missed something

Answer (score -1):

Open Market application.
Tap Menu key.
Select Settings.
Uncheck Notifications. (notify me about updates to apps or games that I've downloaded)

Comment: OP is not talking about notification regarding available updates but notification after updating app.